# 2D Game control question - rotation & movement

Tags: iphone, ipad, transform, rotation

I was wondering if anyone could help me get started or pointed in the right direction. I'm looking to make a simple driving game using core animation. I'm a pretty good obj-c programmer, but when it comes to movement and math, I fail. I want a steering wheel to control the direction of the car, and a forward/backward to control acceleration & deceleration. If anyone can help me with the steering wheel code, I would be greatly appreciated! So basically I need help making a circle that can rotate with 1 finger drag, and i'll pass it's transform values to my car view ( i think i can handle the accel/deccel code) Any takers? :) Also, I have 2 invites for dribbble.com to give away, anyone who helps me, id be glad to give one out to.

---

grady, totowtwo, thanks for both your answers, I appreciate it. I;ve gotten to the point where I can rotate a "steering wheel" and it will rotate my "car", I also got it to move forwards and backwards. Just need to moving to be more realistic... Here is a link to the xCode project, http://www.cl.ly/7VBU, kept it very simple so if anyone looks at it - it will be easy to change / add code. So, if anyones wants to look at it,and help me make the movement more realistic, i'd be forever in your debt! :) thanks!

Comment: Could you share your steering wheel code?

Answer (score 0):

A starting point would be to recognize that a typical car steering wheel has 900 degrees of movement, whether you want that for the finger wheel or not is a design decision. The wheels in a car typically point about 30 degrees off +z at maximum rotation of the wheel. You could use a simple linear transformation from steering wheel angle to wheel angle.

From there, Car delta angle is a function of wheel angle times forward distance. As the car moves forward, you can imagine tracing the tangent of a circle with an infinite radius when you are pointing straight ahead, and a circle of smaller radius (~4x car length) when steering wheel is full tilt.

Of course, feel free to discard the design rules of typical vehicles. Give your users fun drive trains like holonomic robots have!

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert but you could probably do something like:

```
CGPoint centerOfWheel;
CGPoint currentTouchPoint;
float radians = atan2(currentTouchPoint.x-centerOfWheel.x, currentTouchPoint.y-centerOfWheel.y);
```

then apply the transformation to the wheel ... of course you will want to make the transformations cumulative on the view over a distance, as continued turning of the wheel will result in continued turning.

also to make it feel more real, and less responsive you may want to use a lesser degree of turn, so that turning the wheel in once circle doesn't result in a whole circle turn of the vehicle. you will have to play around.